# Connection Firebase to Flutter failing

Tags: flutter, firebase

Given below is the error im getting ..
Tried a lot to fix it.. cant seem to get what is wrong

PS I am trying to run using flutter run in Linux from VSCode

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Linux in debug mode...
main.dart:1
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:42365/Ry6K9giFyvk=/ws
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)
#0      FirebaseCoreHostApi.initializeCore
messages.pigeon.dart:210
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      MethodChannelFirebase._initializeCore
method_channel_firebase.dart:29
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp
method_channel_firebase.dart:73
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      Firebase.initializeApp
firebase.dart:43
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: You need to add your code for anyone to be able to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please add your code to let us know what goes wrong.

Comment: You don't mention that you did all setup for firebase, there is so many steps to connect firebase with google cloud in flutter... did you do all steps? if yes share your code so the other can figure out and help you. Thank you.